# Asset path error while uploading wheel to github release

Tags: python, github-actions

I have this workflow: [ci-cd.yml](https://github.com/ruipiresc/ruipiresc.python.wraplite/blob/6b05aabc4855c560bdcd06804df25606a526877c/.github/workflows/ci-cd.yml)

My purpose is to:

1. Build and publish my code on any new tag
2. Create a release for that version
3. Upload the wheel into the release

So far step 1 and 2 are ok.
Step 3 is giving me troubles.

Any help is welcome

```html
Upload Release Asset0s
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ***
Run actions/upload-release-asset@v1
  with:
    upload_url: https://uploads.github.com/repos/***/***.python.wraplite/releases/29475003/assets{?name,label}
    asset_path: /home/runner/work/***.python.wraplite/***.python.wraplite/dist/wraplite-0.2.3-dev26-py3-none-any.whl
    asset_name: wraplite-0.2.3-dev26-py3-none-any.whl
    asset_content_type: application/zip
  env:
    pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.5/x64
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ***
##[error]ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/runner/work/***.python.wraplite/***.python.wraplite/dist/wraplite-0.2.3-dev26-py3-none-any.whl'
```

I also have an [open issue on my github repo](https://github.com/ruipiresc/ruipiresc.python.wraplite/issues/10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the line

> /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.5/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:454: UserWarning: Normalizing '0.2.3-dev26' to '0.2.3.dev26'
> warnings.warn(tmpl.format(**locals()))

in your  `Publish python package` step.

This causes a mismatch (`.` vs `-` after `0.2.3`):

Actual file: `dist/wraplite-0.2.3.dev26-py3-none-any.whl`

File that you're trying to upload: `dist/wraplite-0.2.3-dev26-py3-none-any.whl`